# Synchronous postMessage

Tags: javascript, postmessage

Is there a way to make postMessage "a synchronous call"? 
meaning:

- do postMessage from parent to iFrame
- wait until parent gets back a message (sent from the iFrame)

For example:

```
function doSomething() {
   targetiFrame.postMessage('actionA');
   handleMessage('actionA').then(function() {
      return true;
   });
}

function handleMessage(action) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   });
}
```

Of course, this will not work as I trigger handleMessage while it should be triggered only when the right message received. Is there a way to wait until 'actionA' message received and only then end the function with return true?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/140350). Why do you need to make this synchronous? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: What i actually need is that doSomething will return a response of a function that can run only in the iFrame

Comment: @co.zohar - Was this solved? if yes, can you please answer your own question? 10x

Comment: @vsync Hi, check answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem like this:

```
let doSomethingResolveCallback;
let doSomethingRejectCallback;

function doSomething() {
  return new Promise(resolve, reject) => {
    doSomethingResolveCallback = resolve;
    doSomethingRejectCallback = reject;
    targetiFrame.postMessage('actionA');
  }
}

// handles messages from the iFrame
function handleMessage(event) {
   if (event.action === "answerToActionA") {
     doSomethingResolveCallback(event.data);
   }
}
```

Comment: What makes this solution *synchronous* ?